# why list doesn't work similar like array in c++

Tags: c++, list

Why my code is not printing the value 2 in l[0]?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
list<int> l;
int main()
{
    l.push_back(2);
    cout<<l[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this even compile, afaict [list doesnt have that operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) (did you mean to use std::vector?)

Comment: Because `std::list` is a linked list. You have to iterate over all previous elements to get to the preferred index. See:https://thispointer.com/c-how-to-get-element-by-index-in-list/. If you want something like python's lists use `std::vector`. Aslo both `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` is considered bad practice

Comment: Different isn't the same. -- Fred Picker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, List containers are implemented as doubly-linked lists. They excel in performance when inserting and moving elements around, but they must be traversed. They lack direct access to the elements by their position.

What you probably would rather have is a `vector`. Vectors allow for direct access:

```
vector<int> l;
int main()
{
    l.push_back(2);
    cout << l[0];
    return 0;
}
```